# How can i perform order by where id =5 desc in yii 2

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

```
Customer::find()->where(['<>','customer_id', '7'])->all()
```

Currently the code above allows me to find all the customer where their customer id is not 7. Now, I want to find all

> where customer_id is not 7 order by customer id = 5 desc

I know that I can do that in mysql using:

```
SELECT * FROM mydatabase.customer_id where customer_id <> 7 order by customer_id = 5 desc;
```

but how can I do that with `yii2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use active record :

```
Customer::find()->where(['<>','customer_id', '7'])
->orderBy([new \yii\db\Expression('FIELD (customer_id, 5) DESC')])->all();
```

Comment: @IvanCloud. mind upvoting answer, so it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
$result = (new \yii\db\Query())
         ->select('*')
         ->from('customer')
         ->where(['<>','customer_id', '7'])
         ->orderBy([new \yii\db\Expression('FIELD (customer_id, 5) DESC')])
         ->all();
```